# Universal Remote-wireless keyboard & mouse

Tags: wireless, keyboard, xbmc

Hello I've got XBMC setup running on Ubuntu 10.10, so far I use a USB keyboard and mouse plugged into the PC to control it, and the PC in general. Can anyone recommend a single wireless integrated keyboard and mouse (one device with both functions), that can connect wirelessly to my computer so that I can navigate, type and do all the functionality I have with 2 wired devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fairly easily use a laptop, if that's interesting to you. It's actually quite easy to setup and configure. You'll install QuickSynergy (It's in Ubuntu Software Center) on both your mediacenter and your laptop and then configure the mediacenter to connect to your laptop.

If you're not familiar with it, Synergy lets you define another computer similar to having an external monitor. That is to say, you'll move the mouse pointer outside of the laptops screen and then you control the other PC with both mouse and keyboard.

One thing you should be aware of, is that the controlling PC, a laptop in this case, is called the server and that the mediacenter will be a client. Configuration is quite simple. On the mediacenter, you'll open the "Use" page in QuickSynergy and enter the laptops hostname in the server hostname field, and the mediacenter hostname in the screen name field. Append .local to the hostnames, so if your laptop is called mylaptop, then it becomes mylaptop.local. Click execute.

On the laptop, you run QuickSynergy, but this time, you open the "Share" page. Enter the mediacenter hostname in one of the four fields (again, this will be like mediacenter.local) and click Execute. You can now move the mouse pointer from the laptop and onto the mediacenter, and the keyboard and mouse will work as if you had a keyboard and mouse connected to the mediacenter.

I know it's not exactly what you asked for, but it is a completely free solution as long as you just have a laptop. :)

It works with OS X and Windows too, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

QuickSynergy additional guide from (http://code.google.com/p/quicksynergy/wiki/RunningQuickSynergy)
worked ok with XBMC, the screen mouse movement wasn't 100% but it was ok. An alternative is remote desktop. For my setup I setup the mediacentre PC(running XBMC) to allow remote access. So I could log in from the laptop(also running ubuntu). And it works just as well as QuickSynergy. Just another suggestion